# Debug App Settings.bundle Hidden/Disabled in Debug App Archive Using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm trying to push an app of mine out to TestFlight so my QA group can get their hands on it but am having a problem that I'm encountering. I recently added a run/build script to the app's Xcode project that conditionally enables/disables the Settings.bundle resource based on the build configuration (DEBUG=enabled, RELEASE=disabled) -- the resource is used only as an internal debug utility so I don't want it enabled when I decide to build it in release mode or push it out to the App Store.

I tested out that build script modification I made by running my app on a physical iPad device right from Xcode and I got the results I expected to get -- when I ran the project from Xcode in Debug on my iPad, I saw the app settings available and when I ran the project from Xcode in Release on my iPad, the settings menu was not available for the app. This all goes down the crapper when I decide to ARCHIVE my app in Debug (so that I can push it out to TestFlight). Long story short, the debug archive hides my app settings menu when it should NOT hide it. Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Your building your app in debug mode. Build it in release mode.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I want to build the app in Debug mode because I want the app settings to be available in the iOS Settings menu for debug purposes. Release doesn't give me that menu as expected when I run the app directly through Xcode, but when I ARCHIVE the app (for distribution purposes) using the Debug configuration, the app settings menu is hidden when it shouldn't be.